# PHPBB add tag SPOIL. Lightbox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, lightbox, bbcode, phpbb

I have phpbb 3.1.9

I'm going to add new BBCode [spoil] using native functionality (from admin area).

I have following:

```
[spoiler={TEXT1}]{TEXT2}[/spoiler]

<div style="margin: 8px auto; border: 1px solid #C3CBD1; border-left-width: 2px">
   <div style="background: #E9E9E6; height: 19px; font-size: 0.9em; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer" onclick="hidn = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1]; btn = this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]; if (hidn.style.display != '') { hidn.style.display = ''; orimg = btn.src; btn.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCQAJAMQeAOLt+ff8//z+/4CRxo2by7vF6a254X6PxICQw87a74CQxuXo84CQxM/b7/H6/v7+/oGRxouayoGSxv7+/8LN7IqZyv7//4KSxur0/MrV74OTx9Ld8trl9gwMDP///wAAACH5BAEAAB4ALAAAAAAJAAkAAAU4oFcpwzFAkWgUVLZxCQGxLgdgGtS+t6NJmY5QOEFcNo/kZGLRXGwYR0DQjDSiU8uCIJJIGJdLKgQAOw=='; } else { hidn.style.display = 'none'; btn.src = orimg; }">
<a href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCQAJAMQfAIqZyoGSxv3+/trl84CQxYCRxn6PxMXQ7efq9H+Pwtnk8oKTxoCQxKy44QAAANvl9rvG6fD5/o2by4GRxvb8//v9//7+/ubw+v39/ouayoKSxoOTx/7+/wwMDP///////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAJAAkAAAU84AdoGkNmX4Z4HldRirSxXMdF1zK7nXU9mk2t4+h0BIlNhWPpYTCBDQXXwRwggczgJ8BAGhLRZGIoEFAhADs=" data-lightbox="post-gallery">      
<img style="margin: 0; padding: 5px 5px 0" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCQAJAMQfAIqZyoGSxv3+/trl84CQxYCRxn6PxMXQ7efq9H+Pwtnk8oKTxoCQxKy44QAAANvl9rvG6fD5/o2by4GRxvb8//v9//7+/ubw+v39/ouayoKSxoOTx/7+/wwMDP///////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAJAAkAAAU84AdoGkNmX4Z4HldRirSxXMdF1zK7nXU9mk2t4+h0BIlNhWPpYTCBDQXXwRwggczgJ8BAGhLRZGIoEFAhADs=" /> </a>
      {TEXT1}
   </div>
   <div style="display: none; background: #F5F5F5; border-top: 1px solid #C3CBD1; padding: 6px">
      {TEXT2}
   </div>
</div>
```

Lightbox doesn't work inside spoiler.

> https://github.com/VSEphpbb/lightbox

Looks like it happen because of order of rendering. And it's necessary to put some defer function to let page be rendered. Maybe somebody have workable spoiler BBCode or know quick solution without core modifications?

Answer (score 0):

I would add some extra delimiters to the parameter, because otherwise it'll pick up the end of the first BBCode within it as the end of the tag. And make it unique, so that the delimiters don't conflict. For example:

```
[spoiler=@{TEXT1}@]{TEXT2}[/spoiler] (because quotes are already used by the [quote] tag)
```